# execute python file from python script with arguments{jenkins]

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, subprocess

I am running a python script.
environment : Windows10
python version :2.7.14
I am trying to run this file in jenkins execute batch command(generally used for windows command line option)
Here is the code.

p1.py:

```
import subprocess
command="C:/users/python test1.py C:/Users/test1.html"
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
```

It always throws an error while running from Jenkins:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\'

C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\test1>python p1.py 
python: can't open file 'p1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But the same works when I run it from Command prompt.

Anything am I missing here?

I have tried with

```
os.system("python p1.py test1.html")
```

But I get the same error.

EDIT: Its working now, missing was system path

Comment: Does `C:\Users\C5242046\.jenkins\workspace\test1\p1.py` exist?

Comment: yes that exists...but I have changed it now since when I asked this question that existed but now  it did not exists

Answer (score -3):

I use `exec(open(“myfile.py”).read())`

Comment: please notice I have to pass the html file (test1.html) as sys arguments too & I have tried exec option too.